# Aggregate/Resample timeseries dataframe keeping original timeseries index, tallying up as per original timeseries row

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a timeseries dataframe, it looks like this..

```
                    price  volume
timestamp          
2020-05-01 00:00:00 51      1                                                            
2020-05-01 03:00:00 50      1
2020-05-01 06:00:00 51      1
2020-05-01 09:00:00 52      2
2020-05-01 12:00:00 53      1
2020-05-01 15:00:00 51      1
2020-05-01 18:00:00 50      2
2020-05-01 21:00:00 51      1
```

What I would like to do is resample the data into a 12h period, KEEP the original 3h period index but cum the volume and ohlc the price..

The output would look like this..

```
                      open  high   low   close   volume
timestamp          
2020-05-01 00:00:00   51     51     51     51      1                                                            
2020-05-01 03:00:00   51     51     50     50      2
2020-05-01 06:00:00   51     51     50     51      3
2020-05-01 09:00:00   51     52     50     52      5
2020-05-01 12:00:00   53     53     53     53      1
2020-05-01 15:00:00   53     53     51     51      2
2020-05-01 18:00:00   53     53     50     50      4
2020-05-01 21:00:00   53     53     50     51      5
```

So as you can see..
I have kept the same time frame index (3h) but aggregated the data into 12h consolidation blocks.

Obviously I would look to do this as efficiently as possible.

I've checked the docs and doesn't look like any easy way to do this. Hoping greater more experienced minds out there can come up with something.
I thought about maybe a rolling window ?